# Card game combination

Tags: combinations, permutation, poker

This is more like a maths question but since I am trying to create a code for that, I will ask here.

## Situation:

I have poker cards and each people have 14 cards on their hands. This is the game I am trying exactly [this](http://www.pagat.com/rummy/okey.html).

## Aim:

I want to make a rating system for the computer decide if it is better to take a card from the deck or continue with the hand.

## Rules:

The same card type can make rows like spades 3-4-5-6-7 and the different card types make a row as spades 3 -hearts 3 - diamonds 3 - clubs 3. The only important rule is those rows has to be more than 2 cards so spades 3-4 is not good

## Extra role:

I want computer to array the cards according to the best combination when the cards dealt mixed.

I have come with 2 solutions:

1. Making a permutation of 14 cards and give rating according ot the neighbours of the card so have a general point. This has around 80 trillion possibilities and each has to be rated, that takes huge amount of time and I want a solution that can calculate in 1-3 seconds.
2. Choosing each card and searching for possible rows, if there is a row with more than 3 members, subtract from the list and try others. Trying it for all cards and row possibilities is giving me a good amount. But this method has disadvantages of being too complicated and having many extra checks such as if the card is better suited as same type row or different type of row.

Has anybody come up with a problem like that or have an idea to give me the right direction?